# Move Aurora DB from region Ireland to MySQL region Frankfurt

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to move my db from region Ireland to Frankfurt. Problem is that Frankfurt does not support Aurora. How can I migrate Aurora db from Ireland region to simple MySQL in Frankfurt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, you can migrate to Aurora. Enjoy!